# Is it possible to use an enumeration as the subscript to a MATLAB vector or Map?

Tags: matlab, oop, enumeration, subscript

I an looking to use an enumeration to access elements of an array or dictionary but having no luck.

Enum:

```
classdef Enumeration1 < uint32
    enumeration
        Left    (1);
        Right   (2);
        Neither (3);
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
directions(Enumeration1.Left) = 7;
```

To me this should be the same as

```
directions(1) = 7;
```

but I get 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals'.

alternatively when I use a `containers.Map` object, all examples I see have keys as strings. When I use an enumeration I get 'Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container'. I can see from `help containers.Map` that uint32 is an acceptable key type.

How can I effectively index objects using an enumerated value?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Floris I'm using 2010b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the example given at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html , you will see that the value of `Enumeration1.Left` is not the value `1`, but instead an object. You can confirm this by examining the object returned:

```
a = Enumeration1.Left;
whos a
display(a)
```

This shows you that `a` is an object of class `Enumeration1`, with size `108 bytes` and value `Left`. Converting `Left` into `1` is done with

```
b = uint32(a);
```

So the following should work:

```
directions(uint32(Enumeration1.Left)) = 7;
```

Interestingly - when I use Matlab 2012a, I can actually use the syntax you have above, and Matlab doesn't complain.

Comment: Oh no, schoolboy error, in my actual code the enumerated values started from zero, an entirely incorrect value for a vector index. Thanks for your help though, in 2010b the syntax works also.

Comment: Glad to help. I was surprised to think the syntax changed, but it's been known to happen... I learnt something by looking at the problem more closely, so it wasn't a waste of time :-)

Answer (score 3):

In general to [use objects as indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br1dvl5-1), define a [`subsindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsindex.html) method for your class.

Note that against everything else in MATLAB, `subsindex` must return zero-based indices.

```
classdef E < uint32
    enumeration
        Left    (1);
        Right   (2);
        Neither (3);
    end

    methods
        function ind = subsindex(obj)
            ind = uint32(obj) - 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Example:

```
>> x = 1:10;
>> x(E.Right)
ans =
     2
```

Note that even without the defining the `subsindex` method, classes that inherit from builtin type should work as indices as usual (at least it worked this way in my R2013a version).

---

If you want to work with containers.Map, you must explicitly cast the enumeration as `uint32`. I think the `containers.Map/subsref` method does not use `isa` to test the type of the indexing term, instead use something like `strcmp(class(obj),'..')` which explains the error message:

```
Error using containers.Map/subsref
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```